# Differentiation of mixture Gaussians in R

Tags: r, differentiation

Is there any way that you can differentiate mixture Gaussians in R? To get the density of a mixture Gaussian distribution, I have used the following code:

```
dnorm_mix <- function(x, weights, means, sds) {
  value <- 0
  for (i in 1:length(weights)) {value <- value + weights[i]*dnorm(x, mean = means[i], sd = sds[i])}
  return(value)
}
```

Can anyone help me find expressions for the first and second derivative of this? I've tried to use the 'deriv' built-in function in R, but gives an error 'dnorm_mix' is not in the derivatives table.

Thanks!

Comment: deriv would probably work if you wrote out the pdf using elementary functions. Alternately the numDeriv package offers functions for numerical differentiation.

Comment: I assume you mean the derivative with respect to x. Since the Gaussian mixture density is a linear combination of Gaussian densities, the derivatives of the GM density are linear combinations of derivatives of Gaussian densities.